# How to remove a ^M character java

Tags: dos, truncate, carriage-return

**Problem:**
*If String ends with \r, remove \r*

I started with something like this

```
if (masterValue.endsWith(CARRIAGE_RETURN_STR)) {
  masterValue = masterValue.replace(CARRIAGE_RETURN_STR, "");
}
```

where

```
public static final String CARRIAGE_RETURN_STR = (Character.toString(Constants.CARRIAGE_RETURN));
public static final char CARRIAGE_RETURN = '\r';
```

This seems awkward to me.

Is there an easy way to just remove \r character?

I then moved on to this:

```
if (value.contains(CARRIAGE_RETURN_STR)) {
   value = value.substring(0, value.length()-3);
```

//-3 because we start with 0 (1), line ends with \n (2) and we need to remove 1 char (3)

But this too seems awkward .

Can you suggest a easier, more elegant solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regexes can support end-of-string anchoring, you know. (See [this Javadoc page](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) for more information)

```
myString.replaceAll("\\r$", "");
```

This also takes care of fixing \r\n --> \n, I believe.

Answer (score 3):

I'd write it like this:

```
if (masterValue.endsWith("\r")) {
    masterValue = masterValue.substring(0, masterValue.length() - 1);
}
```

I see no point in creating a named constant for the String "\r".

By the way, your second attempt is incorrect because:

1. `String.contains("\r")` tells you if the String contains a carriage return, not if it ends with a carriage return,
2. the second argument of `String.substring(int, int)` is the index of the end character; i.e. the position first character that should NOT be in the substring, and
3. the length of `"\r"` is one.